# Exporting block with features

Tags: blocks, importing-exporting, features

I want to export block with features.I have installed features_extra and enabled fe_block and then exported my block into my feature. But there's only hook_default_fe_block_settings. I want to export into code also a content of block. So block viem etc. How can I do that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Blockexport](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockexport)**

Functionality List

- It will import all system specific block into a feature.
- Import all custom blocks within a feature.
- Import all system blocks associated with content type
- Import all block roles
- No configuration is required.
- This module not create any table in your database to minimise the performance issue as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading [Features Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_extra) and see if that's already fixed.

Alternatively use [Boxes](https://www.drupal.org/project/boxes) module which is a reimplementation of the custom blocks (boxes) that the core block module provides. Or use Mini panels in [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module.